# Flask unable to serve the .js file in the static directory, but able to serve the .css file. .js file status is 404

Tags: flask, raspberry-pi, pycharm

Flask is able to serve the .css file in the static directory, but not the .js file in the same directory.

What I have tried :

```
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="../static/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

However, both these lines work for the .css file :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='bootstrap.min.css') }}">
```

When reloading in Firefox, I press `Ctrl + Shift + R` to force a full refresh so as far as I know, the .css file is not being pulled from the cache.

The Flask console reports that the status of the .js file is 404 and so does the browser. The status of the .css file is 200.

Here is the tree (bootstrap.css and bootstrap.min.css are on the same level. I'm not sure why PyCharm displays them like this):

[image: Directory tree]

I know that I should serve static files using a proper web server, but this project is a simple settings page for a program that I am running on a Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with PyCharm (sort of). Under Tools > Deployment, "Automatic Upload (Always)" was checked. So I assumed that any change to any of the files in the project would be automatically synchronized. It turns out that they are not. Renaming and moving files from outside PyCharm did not trigger a sync. After right clicking the static directory and selecting Deployment > Upload to [...], the issue was fixed.

It was also a bit of user error. I forgot that I wasn't developing locally.